# Enable forward slashes in site key when setting a cloud page

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

Trying to create a url [www.example.com/urlgoeshere/faqs](http://www.example.com/urlgoeshere/faqs) but whenever I try to add a forward slash in the url I get an error. I can save dashes, underscores but no forward slashes. Is it possible through some setting?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to construct cloudpage URLs with “/” signs for structuring paths for SEO or similar.

You will receive a "bad request" - I have reached out to Support about it in the past and they have confirmed this to be expected behavior.

I still have the support ticket's case id as the source, but it was for a customer project so I cannot really share.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Will let my client know this is not possible.